# Bootstrap Progress Bar text not center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap progress bar do display an amount of money spent vs the limit.

There are times where this will exceed the limit and the progress bar will just be full.

However, when it exceeds it too much, you can no longer see the text on top of it because its "centered" with the bars progress which is off the div.

Works like normal:

```
  <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%;">
    50%
  </div>
</div>
```

Text is no longer shown on the bar as it exceeds the div

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="200" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 200%;">
    200%
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E9chu/

My hope is that I can say if it exceeds the max amount (I can specify this) then set the class to `blah` which tells the text to now center in the `progress` div and not the `progress-bar` div

Comment: Have you considered using the [HTML5 meter tag](http://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/)? I think it suits best to you problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I would rather stay with what I've got an tweak if if needed. Needing to support older browsers :/

Comment: I hear you... then below's my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule to your CSS:

```
.progress-bar {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: so simple it makes me sad :(

Comment: It happens. Sometimes you're too into coding that it takes someone else to spot a simple thing. ;-)